# How to run jquery codes before and after ajax call?

Tags: 7, entities, javascript, ajax

I want to create a *loading code while the ajax call is not yet complete*, AND enable my jquery code *after calling the ajax of drupal form*. The **ajax** I'm referring to is the "**Add new field/Add more**" of unlimited field. I don't have a custom module for that. I'm just using what drupal already has.

This is the code that triggers the Ajax of the form:

```
$('input[name="field_collection_add_more"]').mousedown();
```

I can't use the `$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){}); nor ajaxStart`
function of the jquery because I only want my functions to run on that specific ajax call for that specific field.

How can I use the **beforeSend:** and **success:** when the ajax **add new field** is running?

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: maybe you can use `$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){})` combined with an if statement that checks if a specific div exists or something.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Special Effects AJAX framework command.
 */
Drupal.ajax.prototype.commands.nameOfCommand =  function(ajax, response, status) {
  alert("Hello I'm Maged Eladawy...")  ; // this will be executed after the ajax call
}
```

More [details](http://www.maged.me/blog/drupal-7-execute-javascript-code-after-ajax-call)

Answer (score 0):

There is a `beforeSubmit` function available on the button that fires the ajax call. The `beforeSubmit` function will fire before the ajax.

```
Drupal.behaviors.exampleModule = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {

    // ELEMENT_ID must not include the #
    Drupal.ajax['ELEMENT_ID'].options.beforeSubmit = function(form_values, element_settings, options) {
      // code here
    };
  }
};
```

If you `console.log` your `Drupal.ajax['ELEMENT_ID'].options` you'll see there is a `success` function and a `complete` function that you can also hook into.

Try to keep everything in a Drupal behavior if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you can't use `$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){}); nor ajaxStart`.
However, I think this would be the right approach but, intead selecting the `document` you have to pass in your unique selector for desired field.

```
$('input[name="field_collection_add_more"]', context).ajaxStart(function () {
  // ...
});
$('input[name="field_collection_add_more"]', context).ajaxSuccess(function () {
  // ...
});
```

See [Fade views content on views ajax pager action in Drupal 7](https://cornel.co/article/fade-views-content-views-ajax-pager-action-drupal-7) for a real example.

Comment: what about Drupal 8, it doesn't work for me, any idea please !

Answer (score -1):

You can read that article [Understanding JavaScript behaviors in Drupal](https://www.lullabot.com/articles/understanding-javascript-behaviors-in-drupal).
And if you want your code run after ajax call back, you need write code same example

```
Drupal.behaviors.exampleModule = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
    // Code here.
  }
};
```

> Here are some examples:
>
> - CTools calls it after a modal has been loaded.
> - Media calls it after the media browser has been loaded.
> - Panels calls it after in-placeediting has been completed.
> - Views calls it after loading a new page    that uses AJAX.
> - Views Load More calls it after loading the next chunk    of items.
> - JavaScript from custom modules may call    Drupal.attachBehaviors() when they add or change parts of the page.